# SQL Server record locking behaves differently depending on record count

Tags: sql-server, locking

I am using row locking with the SQL Server. I have some locations on SQL Server Express and some on SQL Server 2012 full. I have a table, linked_invoices with a primary key and a ticket_id field. The ticket_id field may be duplicated within the table.

I have a non clustered index (ix_ticket_id) on the ticket_id field.

The query I use to pull the data is

```
select * from linked_invoices  With (rowlock xlock)  where ticket_id = 2000074703
```

I have discovered that with tables that have less than 500 records, the ENTIRE table is locked.

With locations that have more than 500 records, only the records with `ticket_id = 2000074703` are locked.

I have tried forcing the with(index) option to force the query optimizer to use ix_ticket_id but that does not help.

```
SELECT *
FROM linked_invoices WITH (ROWLOCK XLOCK INDEX (ix_ticket_id))
WHERE ticket_id = 2000084790
```

I have also tried disabling the lock_escalation
ALTER TABLE linked_invoices SET (LOCK_ESCALATION=DISABLE)

I have also tried rebuilding the index ix_ticket_id and turning allow_page_locks off

```
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF
```

The only solution I have been able to come up with is to add bogus records into the table. Which I hate doing because I am very picky about keeping my database clean.

Has anyone run into this issue and maybe have another solution?

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of the table lock? The query optmizer does it because it's most likely the most efficient way of doing it.

Comment: I need to force a record lock vs a table lock. One user  will need to add new records or edit other records while another user is editing a different record.